# Jumpy (buggy) glyph map icons on mouse rollover/rollout

Tags: jquery, css, glyphicons

In my [initial task with the help of RoelN, I was able to convert the provinces of South Africa into SVG maps and piece the map together quite nicely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21348355/province-glyph-font-sizes-not-lining-up-interactive-map-of-south-africa/21380194#comment32284767_21380194)

I now need to animate this map which I have started doing but because the maps are all absolutely positioned and overlapping one another it is buggy when you try to select the right map.

Simple animation:

- Rollover a province, province scales up by 50%
- Rollout of current province, map scales back to original size.

Perhaps the best way to do this is to deactivate all other maps when the current map is in **activate** mode?

Here's the latest Fiddle (aaaaaargh not allowed to post Fiddle links! so much duplication and I have a working version over at jsFiddle!!!!) **EDIT: See jsFiddle link in comment below**

Here's the code.

```
<div class="maps">
    <div class="mini-map-wrapper">
        <div class="mini-map">
            <span class="prov-North-West"></span>
            <span class="prov-Limpopo"></span>
            <span class="prov-Mpumalanga"></span>
            <span class="prov-KwaZulu-Natal"></span>
            <span class="prov-Gauteng"></span>
            <span class="prov-Free-State"></span>
            <span class="prov-Eastern-Cape"></span>
            <span class="prov-Western-Cape"></span>
            <span class="prov-Northern-Cape"></span>
        </div>                                              
    </div>
</div>

<div class="map-0"></div>
<div class="map-1"></div>
<div class="map-2"></div>
<div class="map-3"></div>
<div class="map-4"></div>
<div class="map-5"></div>
<div class="map-6"></div>
<div class="map-7"></div>
<div class="map-8"></div>


@font-face {
    font-family: 'za-provinces';
    src:url('http://vane.co.za/files/south-african-province-glyphs/fonts/za-provinces.eot');
    src:url('http://vane.co.za/files/south-african-province-glyphs/fonts/za-provinces.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('http://vane.co.za/files/south-african-province-glyphs/fonts/za-provinces.woff') format('woff'),
        url('http://vane.co.za/files/south-african-province-glyphs/fonts/za-provinces.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('http://vane.co.za/files/south-african-province-glyphs/fonts/za-provinces.svg#za-provinces') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

.maps {
        position: relative;
        .mini-map-wrapper {
            position: absolute;
            top: 10px;
            left: 50px;
            width:  330px;
            height: 330px;
            padding:10px;
            background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);;
        }
        .mini-map {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0 auto;
            background-color: white;
            position: relative;
        }
    }

    [class^="prov-"], [class*=" prov-"] {
        font-family: 'za-provinces';
        speak: none;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-variant: normal;
        text-transform: none;
        line-height: 1;

        /* Better Font Rendering =========== */
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
        -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;


        font-size:8em;
        color: $corp-blue;

    }

    .prov-Western-Cape:before, 
    .prov-Northern-Cape:before, 
    .prov-Free-State:before, 
    .prov-Eastern-Cape:before, 
    .prov-North-West:before, 
    .prov-Mpumalanga:before, 
    .prov-Limpopo:before, 
    .prov-KwaZulu-Natal:before, 
    .prov-Gauteng:before
    {
        position: absolute;
    }


    .prov-Western-Cape:before {
        content: "\e600";
        bottom: 0;
        left: 30px;
        color: green;
    }
    .prov-Northern-Cape:before {
        content: "\e601";
        bottom: 84px;
        left: 14px;
        color: orange;
    }
    .prov-Free-State:before {
        content: "\e602";
        bottom: 51px;
        left: 114px;
        color: yellow;
    }
    .prov-Eastern-Cape:before {
        content: "\e603";
        bottom: 8px;
        left: 98px;
        color: pink;
    }
    .prov-North-West:before {
        content: "\e604";
        top: 116px;
        left: 93px;
        color: #0f0;
    }
    .prov-Mpumalanga:before {
        content: "\e605";
        bottom: 94px;
        left: 169px;
        color: brown;
    }
    .prov-Limpopo:before {
        content: "\e606";
        top: 80px;
        right: 62px;
        color: #87ceeb;
    }
    .prov-KwaZulu-Natal:before {
        content: "\e607";
        bottom: 52px;
        right: 32px;
        color: teal;
    }
    .prov-Gauteng:before {
        content: "\e608";
        top: 126px;
        left: 154px;
        color: red;
    }


var provArr =  [["prov-Eastern-Cape"    , "map-0"],
               ["prov-Free-State"       , "map-1"],
               ["prov-Gauteng"          , "map-2"],
               ["prov-KwaZulu-Natal"    , "map-3"],
               ["prov-Limpopo"          , "map-4"],
               ["prov-Mpumalanga"       , "map-5"],
               ["prov-North-West"       , "map-6"],
               ["prov-Northern-Cape"    , "map-7"],
               ["prov-Western-Cape" , "map-8"]
              ];

    // first map is eastern cape is current
    var currProv = provArr[0][2]; 

    // deactivate all maps first
    function deActivateMaps () {

        jQuery.each( provArr, function( i, val ) {
            jQuery( "." + provArr[i][0] ).hover(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                //do other stuff when a click happens
            });

        });
    }

    jQuery (".map-0").slideDown();

    //affect only the current map
    jQuery.each( provArr, function( i, val ) {

        jQuery( "." + provArr[i][0] ).hover(function() {

            jQuery(this).css("cursor","pointer");
            //jQuery(this).animate({"border":"1px solid red"}, 500);
            jQuery(this).animate({"color":"#efbe5c","font-size":"12em","left":"600px;"}, 500);

                // on click load maps

                jQuery( "." + provArr[i][0] ).click(function() {

                    jQuery("." + currProv).hide();
                    jQuery("." + provArr[i][3]).show();

                    currProv = provArr[i][4];

                });

            }, function() {

                jQuery(this).animate({"font-size":"8em","z-index":"1"}, 500);
                //deActivateMaps ();


        });

    });
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sixfootjames/LY5y5/35/ I've now added all my code above and it seems you are allowed to add jsFiddle links in the comments.

Comment: The `:hover` will trigger once your mouse enters the area containing the glyphs — that'll be messy one way or another. So I don't see an easy fix, and personally would go for SVG or bitmaps at this point. By the way, if you implemented my solution from the previous thread you wouldn't need to position your `:before`s. Not that that would help you with the current issue ;)

Comment: That's a pity, thanks Roel. I will opt for the bitmap version at the moment and look into an SVG option later ;) Thanks for your reply.